# Why does the code print an optional value?

Tags: xcode, swift, option-type

```
var myString = "7"
var possibleInt = Int(myString)
print(possibleInt)
```

The above code prints out:

> Optional(7)

Why does it do this even though I did not use an optional. The string was converted to a number so shouldn't the out be:

> 7

?

```
myString = "banana"
possibleInt = Int(myString)
print(possibleInt)
```

This code will print out nil because type conversion did not work but I don't see how 7 could be an optional.

Comment: If it can be nil, it has to be an Optional.

Comment: @matt Why can it be a nil?

Comment: As you yourself said. It might fail because the string is not a number.

Comment: Might want to read my book http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_why_optionals

Comment: The `Int(string:)` constructor can only return 1 type. It doesn't get to decide that it is going to return a regular `Int` if the conversion succeeds and a `nil` if it doesn't.  It is not possible to return both `nil` and an `Int`.  If you're going to return `nil`, you have to return an `Int?` which is what `Int(string:)` returns.  The return type of a function is determined at compile time, but the value you are passing to be be converted can be determined at run time.

Comment: If you don't want it to be an optional you have to provide a default value. You can use ?? nil coalescing operator. let num = Int("string") ?? 0

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a value (i.e. a String to an Int) it will be an optional - if you tried to run:

```
let num = Int("things")
// num is Optional(nil)
```

This couldn't possibly be a number, so it returns an 'empty' optional.

If you *know* that the string will always be a valid number you can unwrap it unsafely:

```
let num = Int("5")!
// num is 5, not Optional(5)
```

Or if you don't know if the string will be a valid int, you can safely unwrap it:

```
if let num = Int(myString) {
     // Do something with the number
} else {
    // Catch some error
}
```

Comment: The catch with that is that if you do `let num = Int("Hello")!` then the app will crash at runtime. It would be better to add some optional binding rather than explicit unwrapping.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty about optionals is that they create a safety net in your code. If you take another language and try to parse "example123" as an Int, it will crash and the program will terminate. However in Swift, most functions which may otherwise lead to a crash return an optional, so that the program keeps running.

There are two ways you can avoid getting an optional value at the end of your program.

If you are absolutely sure that the input in Int() will be an integer, you can use

```
var possibleInt = Int(myString)!
```

And of course, if myString isn't an integer, your app will crash. However you can securely unwrap it by doing

```
if let possibleInt = Int(myString) {
    // use possibleInt as an int and not an optional
}
// otherwise, the program won't do anything with possibleInt
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Int() method return a optional value, because if your string contain something that is not a number, such as "abc123", Int("abc123") will return nil,
and also, a method return a optional value has not any relationship with what is the method's argument is.

Answer (score 0):

You can see you did not declare a "myString" to any type first declare as string/integer and then try to print that variable. you will get the exact result that you want.

var myString = "7"

var possibleInt: Int;

var possibleInt = Int(myString)

print(possibleInt)